# Run Java instance across multiple servers?

Tags: java, scalability

I have a Java VM running on one machine on my network. It is running out of CPU power on the one machine, is there any way I can spread the process across maybe 2 computers?

Comment: sure you can, there are many different ways to approach that problem.  Giving some context to what your process does may help guide the answers.

Comment: Your basically talking about distributed computing, where the execution of the task is not dependent on the machine.  The basic concept would be to have a "central" server with a list of takes to executed, each machine in the cluster would then request a new task (when they are free) and process it.  When completed, the task would be returned to the server.  At some time later you would be able to poll the sever for completed tasks and get there results.  For example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into Remote Method Invocation which can allow you to execute methods that aren't on the local machine.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a server and a client. You can have the server in a remote location, have the clients process everything, and return data to the server.